# RouteController failed to create a route in acs-engine

Tags: azure, kubernetes, acs, azure-container-service

I'm trying to deploy my cluster using [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine)
I followed the steps everything went good. But then when i go `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` I find some of them in pending state. 
On `kubectl describe nodes` I see this

`NetworkUnavailable     True    Tue, 11 Apr 2017 10:31:20 +0000     Tue, 11 Apr 2017 10:31:20 +0000     NoRouteCreated          RouteController failed to create a route`

I have not used any network plugin and using the azure's default one. 
I have no idea what is wrong.

No of nodes : 1
No of master : 1

Please let me know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen when the service principal does not have Contributor access, scoped to the resource group of the route table.  Once you recreate your service principal with contributor access, this will work.  More information here: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/serviceprincipal.md.

Comment: Yes! I had the reader access. I changed it to contributor and it works fine. Thank you.